# Adding Css class to all <input type'text'> elements? Javascript / Css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to apply a CSS class to every textbox in my site:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="FoodType">FoodType</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="HelpText" name="FoodType" type="text" value="" />
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
```

And I thought, Hey! Easy. I'll add a jquery function to find them all in the masterpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').addClass('textbox');
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately this will also select the submit button. How can i only select input elements that have a text type attribute?

Alternativly is this possible using entirely CSS?

If both these methods are not possible, i guess i will just have to manually add the class to every textbox i make?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

AFAIK it's:

```
$('input[type=text]').addClass('textbox');
```

And you can do similar in the CSS file, but that requires higher version of CSS / depending how broad you want to be with older browsers.

See attribute selectors in [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/take-your-design-to-the-next-level-with-css3/). Note that:

> "Browser support: The only browser that doesn’t support CSS3 attribute selectors is IE6. Both IE7 and IE8, Opera and Webkit- and Gecko-based browsers do. So using them in your style sheet is definitely safe."

Comment: `$('input[type=text]')` will work in IE6 because jQuery will fall back to using its own selector engine rather than the browser's built-in support. `input[type=text] { ... }` in a CSS stylesheet, on the other hand, would fail in IE6.

Comment: @bobince the canonical solution would be parsing the HTML with a RegEx I guess

Comment: How would I do that in CSS or SCSS?

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".post_class").css({padding:"10px",background:"#333",color:"#fff"});

$("#post_button").css({padding:"10px",background:"#333", textAlign:"center",color:"#fff",cursor:"pointer"})

$("#post_button").click(function(){
var input = $("input[name='checkListItem']").val();

$(".post_class").append('<div class="item">' + input + '</div>');

});

});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<form name="checkListForm">

<input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>

</form>

<div id="post_button">Post</div>

<br/>

<div class="post_class"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all so why is this posted here?