# select all text boxes in css

Tags: css, forms, text, input

Is there a way in CSS to select all input elements of type text?

Comment: This is surely a duplicate, but I can't find one.. edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836030/adding-css-class-to-all-input-typetext-elements-javascript-css - close enough?

Comment: That's what I thought!!! If it isn't, it's a good question, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
input[type=text]
{
  //css rules
}
```

> This requires CSS 2.1 and won't work
>   in some older browsers (like IE6)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this requires CSS 2.1 and won't work in some older browsers (like the infamous IE6).

Answer (score 0):

Other than what was mentioned

> ```
> input[type=text]
> {
>   //css rules
> }
> ```

No I don't think so, unless you mark them manually with the same class and select them with the class.

Or you could try JQuery, something like :

```
val text-inputs = $('input[type="text"]');
```

should do the job ;)